# Thousands Input Mask: Make Caret Position Move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below code which is supposed to be an input field that converts its value to have a thousand separator.

I have achieved just what I want, but I still have one little issue, I want to make sure the cursor moves with the input when the thousand separator is added to the output so that they are aligned.

I am trying to get a proof of concept so that I can apply it to a field in ionic, just in case you are wondering why I am not manipulating the input directly.

**How it works**
I have two input fields, the output field below the input field,  the input field has a transparent background and color, to show the values being displayed on the output field.
The thousand separator is added only to the output field based on the value of the input, so you will notice that after a couple on inputs the comma is added making the output longer than the input hence making the cursor misalign since the cursor of the input is what is displayed. ***(I hope my explanation makes sense)***

```js
function addThousandsSeparator(input) {
    var output = input
    if (parseFloat(input)) {
        input = new String(input); // so you can perform string operations
        var parts = input.split("."); // remove the decimal part
        parts[0] = parts[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?!$)/g, "$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
        output = parts.join(".");
    }

    return output;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.input').on('input', function () {
    let input = $(this).val();
    
    let output = addThousandsSeparator(input)
    $('.output').val(output)
    console.log(output)
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .input {
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: #000;
}
.container .output {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input class="output" type="text"/>
  <input class="input" type="tel"/>
</div>
```

Comment: One can't move the cursor, but, combined with something to [detect the caret position](https://gist.github.com/nicolasembleton/5895896), you could move the below element back and forth, sideways, when it is on odd number groups, and the caret position would match their position.

Comment: Hmmm, @LGSon that sounds like something, I was thinking of adding a space character to the input every time a thousand comma is added, and then using a monospaced font family to make sure all characters are same size

Comment: Even at that I still have to detect caret position

Comment: But with that you'll likely get the same issue you have when manipulate the input directly.

Comment: Have you seen this http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/#tutorial or this  https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric .... might be something to either use or see how they did it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function addThousandsSeparator(input) {
        var output = input
        if (parseFloat(input)) {
            input = new String(input); // so you can perform string operations
            input = input.replace(/\,/g,"")
            var parts = input.split("."); // remove the decimal part
            parts[0] = parts[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?!$)/g, "$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
            output = parts.join(".");
        }

        return output;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.input').on('input', function () {
        let input = $(this).val();

        let output = addThousandsSeparator(input)
        $('.input').val(output)
        console.log(output)
      })
    })
```

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .container input {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .container .input {
      background: transparent;
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <input class="input" type="tel" id="someinput"/>
    </div>
```

You can do the above code in the following way

```
    function addThousandsSeparator(input) {
        var output = input
        if (parseFloat(input)) {
            input = new String(input); // so you can perform string operations
            input = input.replace(/\,/g,"")
            var parts = input.split("."); // remove the decimal part
            parts[0] = parts[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?!$)/g, "$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
            output = parts.join(".");
        }

        return output;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.input').on('input', function () {
        let input = $(this).val();

        let output = addThousandsSeparator(input)
        $('.input').val(output)
        console.log(output)
      })
    })


    <div class="container">
      <input class="input" type="tel" id="someinput"/>
    </div>

   .container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .container input {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .container .input {
      background: transparent;
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

For the POC you can look on my fiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/Sakshigargit15/1n0ncu3j/6/

Comment: Did you miss _"...in case you are wondering why I am not manipulating the input directly."_

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought about doing this too, but the problem is when you place the cursor at the middle and hit on backspace, it changes the cursor position to the back again, also I need to do it with two input fields

Comment: And plus one on what @LGSon said

Comment: Okay, I will get back to on this solution as well so that your cursor will be on the place it should be.

Comment: Wrong. Write "100,000", then add any number at any place except end position. Caret going to end.

Comment: It turns out that putting the cursor in the right place after input masking is very complex. I'm still trying to figure it out, but without cursor manipulation, masking feels very broken.